# C++ Understanding the difference between Variables lifetime,and binding lifetime

Tags: c++, binding, lifetime

I have a problem with understanding the concepts of variables lifetime and binding lifetime.

consider the following arbitrary function

Variable lifetime

> Lifetime is the time duration where an object/variable has memory allocated to it.

binding lifetime.

> The period of time between the creation and destruction
>   of a name-to-object binding is called the binding’s lifetime.

by considering the following arbitrary function. I will put my questions as comments

```
void foo (int j)

{ // Does i's lifetime start here?

    int i; // Or does i's lifetime start her? 

    i = j; // does binding lifetime start here?

} // i's lifetime ends
```

-In other words, does i's lifetime start and end with the blocks"{ }" or start with the decleration (int i;) and end with "}".

Comment: Where does the term binding lifetime come from?  It is not in the standard at all.

Comment: I think it builds it before executing every statement. I am not pro though, maybe that's why we need a prototype for every function, so the compiler builds the function before executing it. So, (maybe research project?) I think it is with the blocks/scope "{}"

Comment: @NathanOliver our instructor used this term on his slides and he put that definition. I'm not sure if it's standard or not. :(

Comment: @user3382285 If your instructor defined a term, then ask your instructor what it means.

Comment: Ah.  Well I cannot comment on it then as I have no idea what he is talking about.

Comment: @Yakk I didn't know that binding lifetime is not  the standard. However, variable lifetime is the standard.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for you help.

Comment: I believe your instructor means something like  `{ int x = 0; {int&y = x;} }`. The "binding lifetime" of the name "y" to the object is the inner scope, the object's lifetime is the outer scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable/object lifetime and binding time can sometimes be the same. You will typically see a difference when, for example, a variable/object is **passed by reference** to a subroutine. The variable/object still retains it value but you can no longer access it by **name**. In other words the time between parameter name and the variable that was passed has a shorter lifetime than the variable itself.

```
01 void addOne(int &y) // y created here
02 { 
03     y = y + 1;
04 } // y is destroyed here
05  
06 int main()
07 {
08     int x = 5;
09     std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
10     addOne(x);
11     std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n'; //y's value is displayed here
12     return 0;
13 }
```

> Results: 
> x = 5 
>  x = 6

y has a variable lifetime includes main() and addone() but y has a binding lifetime between lines 01 and 04.

Answer (score 1):

> does i's lifetime start and end with the blocks "{ }" or start with the declaration (`int i;`) and end with "}".

From the C++11 Standard:

> **3.8 Object lifetime [basic.life]**
>
> 1 The *lifetime* of an object is a runtime property of the object. An object is said to have non-trivial initialization if it is of a class or aggregate type and it or one of its members is initialized by a constructor other than a trivial default constructor. [ *Note:* initialization by a trivial copy/move constructor is non-trivial initialization. — *end note* ]
>
> The lifetime of an object of type `T` begins when:
>   — storage with the proper alignment and size for type `T` is obtained, and
>   — if the object has non-trivial initialization, its initialization is complete.
>
> The lifetime of an object of type `T` ends when:
>   — if `T` is a class type with a non-trivial destructor (12.4), the destructor call starts, or
>   — the storage which the object occupies is reused or released.

Here's an example program and its output:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
   Foo() : id(getNextID()) {}

   ~Foo()
   {
      std::cout << "Destroying object " << id << std::endl;
   }

   int id;

   static int getNextID()
   {
      static int nexID = 0;
      return ++nexID;
   }
};

Foo bar()
{
   throw(10);
   return Foo();
}

int main()
{
   int i = 10;         // Lifetime starts as soon as function is entered.
   try
   {
      Foo f1;          // Lifetime starts after initialization is completed.
      Foo f2 = bar();  // Lifetime does not start at all
      int k = 20;      // Lifetime starts as soon as function is entered
                       // even though it is not initialized.
   }
   catch ( ... )
   {
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Destroying object 1
```

Comment: when we say  int i= j; these are 2 steps int i; and i = j;. I think (int i; ) by itself allocates a memory  for i . Do we really need the initialization for i to start it's life?